# Installing kubernetes on windows 10

Tags: kubernetes

I am following the instructions on this page(https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) to install kubernetes on windows 10. I have enabled virtualzation on my system and have installed virtualbox. When i try to start the minikube, it fails with this error:

```
>minikube start
* minikube v1.9.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.18362 Build 18362
* Using the virtualbox driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
*
* [VBOX_VTX_DISABLED] Failed to start virtualbox VM. "minikube start" may fix it. creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory
* Suggestion: Virtualization support is disabled on your computer. If you are running minikube within a VM, try '--driver=docker'. Otherwise, consult your systems BIOS manual for how to enable virtualization.
* Related issues:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4730
```

This is what i get when i do systeminfo from command prompt:

```
 [03]: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Network
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: ***.***.**.*
                                 [02]: ****::****:****:****:****
                           [04]: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
                                 Connection Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2
                                 DHCP Enabled:    No
                                 IP address(es)
                                 [01]: ***.***.**.*
                                 [02]: ****::****:****:****:****
Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to start minikube using this flag: `--no-vtx-check` ?

Answer (score 1):

[VBOX_VTX_DISABLED]  can means that either virtualization is not enabled in BIOS or Hyper-V is running and not allowing to access to VMX.

Assuming that you have enabled the virtualization it is worth checking out the second option and try to disable the Hyper-V.

You can do that by using this command in powershell:

```
  `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`
```

You may also want to disable those two features:

`Virtual Machine Platform` and `Windows Subsystem for Linux` 
Both can be found at `Turn Windows Features on/off`

Please also note that Microsoft is constantly adding features that are enabling hyper-v and prevent virtualbox from using vtx. Depending on system version some of them could be missing in your system but its worth checking them out and disabling them.

- Application Guard
- Credential Guard
- Device Guard
- Containers
- Hyper-V
- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform
- Windows Sandbox
- Windows Server Containers
- Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2)

Remember to do do a cold boot (shut down for 10 seconds and start it up)